# Create & Format JSON objects in R

Tags: json, r

I want to create and format a json object in R(from a dataframe). 
Output Format --
{"base":{K1:V1,K2:V2},"Criteria":{C1:v1,C2:v2}}

Code I'm using currently --

```
K1=c("V1")
K2=c("V2")
dataframe1=data.frame(K1,K2)

C1=c("v1")
C2=c("v2")
dataframe2=data.frame(C1,C2)

toJSON(list(base=dataframe1,Criteria=dataframe2))
```

Current Output --
{"base":[{"K1":"V1","K2":"V2"}],"Criteria":[{"C1":"v1","C2":"v2"}]}

I basically want to get rid of the square brackets "[]" . This output goes into an API which doesn't accept lists as a part of values in the JSON. Any direction is appreciated!

P.S: I have unsuccessfully looked for related threads on Stackoverflow.

Comment: `gsub` them away perhaps?

Comment: or `jsonlite::toJSON(list(base=as.list(dataframe1),Criteria=as.list(dataframe2)), auto_unbox=TRUE)`

Comment: That's a way to go, but I'm looking to keep the complexity as low as possible since the entire thing would run on huge amounts of data. Is there any other way? eg. using a different data structure as opposed to list()

Comment: @hrbrmstr awesome! exactly what I needed thanks!!